# How to use Android Test Orchestrator in command line?

Tags: android, testing, mobile, android-espresso, androidjunitrunner

Am seeing crashes while running tests from CI. Read this article(https://developer.android.com/training/testing/junit-runner#ato-gradle) about using Android Test Orchestrator. Am using adb to run my tests from CI. want to know how do I install orchestrator. apk in command line ?

Answer (score 6):

If using orchestrator, you need the test service apk too.

1. Get the apk:s from web repo, or you local machine. Local path is somethin like:

   `<your cache dir>\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\androidx.test\orchestrator\1.4.0-alpha05\ffa651bbb898f0f2bc93c8e9f1296ed5e77768f5\orchestrator-1.4.0-alpha05.apk`

   `<your cache dir>\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\androidx.test.services\test-services\1.4.0-alpha05\2a8f8a5c3f033d0c33e0faf35c6151713a9b0f9d\test-services-1.4.0-alpha05.apk`
2. Put them somewhere, where accessible from cmd line.
3. Run these lines from that location:

   `adb install -g -r --force-queryable  orchestrator-1.4.0-alpha05.apk`

   `adb install -g -r --force-queryable  test-services-1.4.0-alpha05.apk`

Comment: THANK YOU! The `--force-queryable` parameter is essential for Android 11 and up. Solved a problem I've been struggling with for weeks. Why is this answer downvoted?

Answer (score -1):

I am also struggling but this `--force-queryable` solve my problem.
Thanks #nilzor

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, vote up the answers that you find helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34753102)